# Firebase real database - Query multiple tags (possibly in Arrays)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an app (Android/ iOS/ web) that will need to show a user a feed with the posibility to filter by one or more tags. The current structure I have is:

```
{
  "articles" : {
    "-KXcnfob3Vo3s8bL9WSI" : {
      "title" : "Article 1",
      "description" : "Description of article 1",
      "tags" : [ "Tag 1", "Tag 2", "Tag 3", "etc." ],
      "url" : "websiteURL1.com",

    },
    "-KXcnfob3Vo3s8bL9WSI" : {
      "name" : "Article 2",
      "description" : "Description of article 2",
      "tags" : [ "Tag 1", "Tag 2", "Tag 3", "etc." ],
      "url" : "websiteURL2.com",
    }
   .....
    }
```

Naturally, I can run multiple queries on the client (one per tag) and then merge them but that would be awfully inefficient and difficult to do with pagination (I don't necessarily want to load ALL articles and then merge).

This is as normalised as I could get the data structure to be. I don't mind changing the data structure as the app has not been developed yet.

Comment: Any optimal possible solution for this?

Comment: From my understanding, Firebase is quite limited and will not support more than a basic one field query. It is a stark warning for any serious developer not to be using it for more than a simple demo. Ignore the marketing hype at your peril.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase database - cannot handle these kind of requests.